# I wanted to call the javascript function, when the select option(It is based on for loop) is selected only once

Tags: javascript, velocity

I have the below code in my Velocity template:

```
<tr>        
 <td>
  <input name ="questions" id = "quest" type = "text"  value =  "$!question.question" size="30" style="border: none" readonly/>
 </td>
 <td>

    <select  id="rate" name="rating" **onchange="myFunction()**">
    #set ($values = [0..2])

 #foreach ($value in $values)
   #set ($optValue = $value) 
   #if ($optValue == 0)
    <option value="$optValue" selected>$optValue</option>
   #else
    <option value="$optValue">$optValue</option>
   #end
  #end
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

In my Javascript i am defining the function myFunction().

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var count = document.getElementsByName('rating').length;
  var total = 0;
  for(x=0;x<count;x++)
  {
    var formRating = document.getElementsByName('rating')[x].value;
    var formWeightage = document.getElementsByName('weightage') [x].value;  
    total=formRating + formWeightage;
    console.log(total);
  }
  return total;
};
```

The problem i face here is,
Consider the above velocity generates 5 rows and 5 selected boxes.
When i select first select option value as 1, the js function(myFunction) is called and all the remaining values of the select boxes() are also selected and displayed.
I want to get only the value of the select box i select. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get all options with the `selected`attribute like this:

```
function doSomethingWithSelectedOptions(){
    var selectedElements = document.querySelectorAll("option[selected]");
    // Iteration over all selected elements
    for(var i=0; i<selectedElements.length; i++){
        console.log("Selected element: "+selectedElements[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```